# D3.js scaleOrdinal doesn't support rangeRoundBands method

Tags: d3.js

Getting error on rangeRoundBands method when using D3.js version 4 for ordinal scale. 
Below is the example in D3.js version 3.

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7440840

However with version 4 below code throws an error.

```
var x = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }))
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
var x = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }))
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);
```

In d3 v4

It should have been:

```
var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .padding(0.1);
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6nhGxSlUIaLA6Fw4sKKz?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome :) Coincidently I was on the documentation of scaleBand and you nailed it. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I was using x.rangeBand() instead of x.bandwidth(). Your plnkr helped me...

Comment: Sir, I correct one tiny mistake in your code . please have a check.  ( from a d3.js beginer.)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for Cyril Cherian . 90% of this gentleman’s answer is correct.

The following are inspirational answers. I have passed the test on d3-5.7.2.

```
// old v3 code
var x = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }))
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);




// new v4 code
var x = d3.scaleBand()

// pay attention here ! the next statement is necessary . It is not part of 【conversion from v3 to v4】
.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; })) 

// below is the 【conversion from v3 to v4】
.rangeRound([0, width])
.padding(0.1);
```