# Unexpected value translate parsing transform attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to visualize TSV data into a graph using d3.js. However I am getting the following errors on the console.

> Unexpected value translate(NaN,450) parsing transform attribute.d3.v4.min.js:3:4262
>
> Unexpected value translate(NaN,130.64516129032256) parsing transform attribute.d3.v4.min.js:3:4262
>
> Unexpected value translate(NaN,72.5806451612903)   parsing transform attribute.d3.v4.min.js:3:4262
>
> Unexpected value translate(NaN,203.22580645161293) parsing transform attribute.d3.v4.min.js:3:4262
>
> Unexpected value translate(NaN,319.35483870967744) parsing transform attribute.d3.v4.min.js:3:4262
>
> Unexpected value translate(NaN,145.16129032258067) parsing transform attribute.d3.v4.min.js:3:4262

My code is as follows:

```
<style>

.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var products = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
    return {
      id: id,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, price: d[id]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(products, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(d) { return d.price; }); }),
    d3.max(products, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(d) { return d.price; }); })
  ]);

  z.domain(products.map(function(c) { return c.id; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .text("Price, $");

  var product = g.selectAll(".product")
    .data(products)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "product");

  product.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return z(d.id); });

  product.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {id: d.id, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.price) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
});

function type(d, _, columns) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  for (var i = 1, n = columns.length, c; i < n; ++i) d[c = columns[i]] = +d[c];
  return d;
}

</script>
```

Below is a sample of TSV data:

Date    Accessories_Scrap   CG_Ingot    Rod Sheet_Cutting   Utensil_Scrap   Wire_Scrap

20160701    106             129         132     123             115             127

20160702    106             129         132     123             115             127

20160703    106             128         132     123             115             127

20160704    106             128         132     123             115             127

20160705    106             128         132     123             115             127

Comment: Looks like d.value.date is not a number, which makes sense. What are you trying to do here ? If you are trying to put labels on a chart (xAxis), this is incorrect. You need to pass a domain to the chart so it will display dates within a certain range

Comment: @thatOneGuy I want the xAxis to display the date. How do I pass the domain to the chart? I am newbie to d3.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the error by using scaleBand which should be used in d3 v4.

Instead of:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
```

I have used:

```
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]),
```

Solution based on this answer: [D3.js scaleOrdinal doesn't support rangeRoundBands method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161065/d3-js-scaleordinal-doesnt-support-rangeroundbands-method)